# Rails ActiveRecord escape variable in join clause

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This query works, but is totally open to SQL injection:

```
products = Product.find(pids,
  :select => 'products.*, P.code',
  :joins => "left join product_dist_match P on
    (P.pid = products.pid and P.cid = #{cid})",
)
```

How can I properly escape the cid variable? The `conditions` parameter allows the format `['foo = ?', bar]` for this purpose, but `joins` does not.

I don't want to use `find_by_sql` because then I would need to add the joins and conditions which are part of the model's default scope (that would not be DRY).

**Edit:** My table structure is essentially this:

```
products: pid (primary key)
product_dist_match: pid, cid, code
customers (not used in the query): cid (primary key)
```

Note that this is a read-only database which Rails only has limited involvement with. I am not planning to set up models for all the tables; I just want to do a simple query as described above, without exposing myself to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: can you describe your table structure? this might be possible by using hash conditions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer I found is to use the `.sanitize` method on the model:

```
products = Product.find(pids,
  :select => 'products.*, P.code',
  :joins => 'left join product_dist_match P on
    (P.pid = products.pid and P.cid = ' + Product.sanitize(cid) + ')',
)
```

If you find a better solution, please post it!

Comment: I achieved this in the same way - it seems a bit of a shortcoming of ActiveRecord to assume that one wouldn't want to add conditions into the join, and do so in a safe manner!

Comment: why can't we use P.cid = cid functionality in a where clause?

Comment: @parallelRails If you are aware of a way to rewrite the above query using `where` instead of `left join`, and get identical results, please post it as an answer!

Comment: I'm not very well averse with sql injections and since your question is mostly about it, I'd rather not post as an answer: `Product.select('products.*, P.code').joins('left join product_dist_match P on P.pid = products.pid').where('P.cid = ?', cid)` Again I'm not sure if this stops sql injection and this is not answer but just an improvement, maybe

Comment: Your suggestion is fine on the injection issue, but it will not return the same results as my query. Test case:`create temporary table r (pid integer);
create temporary table p (pid integer, cid integer, code integer);
insert into r values (123);
insert into p values (123, 20, 1);
select r.*, p.code from r left join p on (p.pid=r.pid and p.cid=4);
select r.*, p.code from r left join p on (p.pid=r.pid) where p.cid=4;` Again, if you do have a way to rewrite the query and get identical results, I'd love to see it.

Comment: A left join with `P.cid = cid` in the join clause will still return the rows, with null values for the `product_dist_match` columns. Moving the filtering to the where clause will completely remove the rows from the result.

Comment: To do it in the where clause you need to check for null: where (p.cid=4 or p.cid is null)

Comment: @JoshuaCoady Please test your solution using the test case I provided in the comment above. (It doesn't work.)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be more what you were trying to do.

```
products = Product.find(pids,
    :select => 'products.*, P.code',
    :joins => sanitize_sql_array [
      'left join product_dist_match P on P.pid = products.pid and P.cid = ?', 
       cid
    ]
```